# How to delete shadow of ball in opencv android

Tags: android, opencv

I have some problem when i try to bound circle use findcontour. But i can't use findcontour exactly because it have a shadow of circle like a below picture.

[image]

How can i get just circle and everthing inside it, everything outsideof ball is removed like that (picture is edited by paint):

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the original image where you want to remove the shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Find contour poins.

2) Use RANSAC to estimate circle radius and center for example like here: [RANSAC](https://github.com/Krigu/Gaze/blob/master/GazeLib/detection/pupil/Ransac.cpp) .